# Convergence of the Fourier series of a continuously differentiable function

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I'm taking an introductory course in Fourier analysis and I'm trying to solve the following problem

> Prove that the Fourier series of a continuously differentiable function $f$ on the circle is absolutely convergent.
>   [Hint: Use the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality and Parseval's identity for $f'$.]

I solved it like this
$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} |\hat{f}(n)| \le \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} |\hat{f}(n)|^2 = \dfrac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}|f(x)|^2 < \infty$$

I'm thinking that the equality holds because of Parseval's identity and that the integral is bounded because $f$ is bounded because it's continuously differentiable on the circle.

The problem is that I'm pretty sure that this solution is wrong since I haven't used the information in the hint or the fact that $f$ is differentiable. Indeed, if this solution is correct then this should hold for any continuous $f$? I'm just not sure why this solution is wrong.

The correct solution is available [here](http://www.math.ru.nl/~aldenhoven/notes/solutions.pdf) (page 30)

Comment: The first inequality in your proof is false. "$\geq$" would be right, but this does not help you.

Comment: @PhoemueX Ah, of course! Thank you!

Comment: If $f$ has derivative $g$, then how does $\hat{f}(n)$ relate to $\hat{g}(n)$? Once you get this, then you can use Parseval's theorem and Cauchy-Schwarz.

Comment: The link to the solutions is dead, [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20180127114953/http://www.math.ru.nl:80/~aldenhoven/notes/solutions.pdf) is an archived version.

Comment: Various sites around the web that collect study guides and solution notes have copies of that (lengthy) write-up by Teck-Cheong Lim for "Solutions to some exercises and problems from Stein and Shakarchi’sFourier Analysis."